# Android GCM Pair up Server and Client?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How can I make the server and a client pair up?

I have a server which sends messages using Google Cloud Messaging.
I also have a client on Android which has an app ready to receive.

But i need to get the device id from the client and give it to the server. Is there any other way to pair up the devices?

I want to connect multiple devices to the same server, it this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the GCM registration id from device to server using a HTTP call along with a device ID (ANDROID_ID or IMEI). 
Server can persist the mapping between device and its GCM registration id.
While sending the GCM from server: use GCM regId, server key and project id.

In your first Activity:

```
if (regId.equals(""))
{
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID);
}
else
{
// Send "regId" to server (e.g. using http)
}
```

In your GCMIntentService class:

```
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1)
{
    // Send arg1 to server along with some device Id (e.g. ANDROID_ID or IMEI)
}
```

Yes, it is possible to pair different devices with a server. We have paired up few hundred devices with our server.

Edit:

Device call following URL from code:
    http://www.example.com/updateGcm?id=&gcmId=

Server simply saves/updates the mapping in a database table.
I am afraid I can't provide exact server side code.
We are using a PHP server (not using the jar provided for server)